# Auto repeat with Flowplayer or how to pass callbacks as strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, callback, flowplayer

I have an embedded flash video player on html page,
something like this:

```
<embed id="flash-videojs-31-field-mech"
             name="flash-videojs-31-field-mech"
             src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf"
             width="320"
             height="240"
             type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
             allowscriptaccess='always'
             allowfullscreen='true'
             flashvars="config={'playlist': [  {'url': 'http://example.com/president.mp4', 'autoPlay':true, 'autoBuffering':true} ]}"
             />
```

Now I need to add an auto repeat functionality. I found this solution: http://flowplayer.org/forum/3/20130

Unfortunately, it involves passing function objects around and I have difficulties inserting it into flashvars attribute.

I can't take it as is, cause html snippet is actually generated by third party code and I want to keep number of tweaks minimal.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using flowplayer, then you possibly can modify it after the embed is done.

Try using their [API](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html) and doing something like:

```
$f().onFinish(function() {
  this.stop();
  this.play();
});
```

This should enable autorepeat for all players on your page. You may also use filter to select the players you need.

Comment: unfortunately, looks like $f() doesn't take into account embedded objects, it iterates only javascript wrappers. So my player instance doesn't affected.